# Theano fails to be imported with theano configuration cnmem = 1

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, theano, theano-cuda

Theano fails to be imported with theano configuration cnmem = 1

Any idea how to make sure the GPU is totally allocated to the theano python script?

> **Note:** Display is not used to avoid its GPU usage

**File: .theanorc**

```
cnmem = 1
```

**File: test.py**

```
print 'Importing Theano Library ...'
import theano
print 'Imported'
```

**Output:**

```
$ python test.py 
Importing Theano Library ... 
Killed 
$
```

It only works with cnmem = 0.75

**File: .theanorc**

```
cnmem = 0.75
```

**Output:**

```
$ python test.py
Importing Theano Library ...
Imported
$
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/4302#issuecomment-202067917

> Could you try with 1.0 instead of 1? according to the docs, it needs
>   to be a float. Also, it is limited to 0.95 to allow space for device
>   drivers. So, you can't use the entire GPU memory just like you can't
>   use all of RAM.

Comment: Actually I tried that too with no hope, any fraction value between 0.75 and 1.00 kills the whole thing

Comment: @Karim Is approximately 75% of your GPU memory free?

Comment: Honestly don't know, any idea how can I check that?

Comment: @Karim `watch nvidia-smi`